# QR codes linked to android

Tags: android, qr-code

I am trying to create an android application that is linked to a QR code. I need the user to scan a QR code and be taken to the application which they can then use. I have looked around on the internet where there are many different generators but they are for website,sms,text. Is there a way to link it to an application?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link to the market page of an app with a link like this:

market://details?id=com.example.admob.lunarlander

Turn that link into a QR code like you would for any other URL. When they scan it, this will give the user the option to Install the app if they don't have it, or Launch the app if they do.

ref: http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1620109

Comment: i'm just doing this as a small project, how can i do it if my app is not on the market?

Comment: @user1162494 I don't believe that you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the link to your app's page on the Android Market website. Basically, just go to market.android.com, find your app and use your app's page's url for the QR code.